# What was the date of Michael's birth?

Tags: logical-deduction, time

Michael was so obsessed with his birthday that he always held his birthday party on the exact date and time of his birth. But he didn't hold his birthday for 8 years (he held his 16th birthday and then his 24th birthday). What was Michael's exact date of birth?

Note: Michael was born in the 19th century.

This is an original puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's a classic Feb 29 moment, in this case **Feb 29, 1880**. 
> Like most years ending in -00, 1900 was not a leap year, meaning there was an 8-year gap between two leap years --- 1896 where he would've been 16, and the next available leap year, 1904, where he would've been 24.

Comment: Excellent! That's the answer.